# 83 Bent Yod in Torah. Anyone know them?

Tags: hebrew

I came across this word קָטֹנְתִּי in Gen 32:11.

On page 295 of Artscroll's Davis edition of the Baal HaTurim's commentary there is a footnote which says that there are 83 bent Yod in Torah, of which this is one.

I found this very intriguing.

Can anyone tell me the other 82?

Comment: @RichardGreen I am curious about your source, but don't have access to that sefer. Could you attach a photo of the passage in question?

Answer (score 3):

The footnote you mention is referencing the work *Sefer Tagin*, which does indeed list all of the instances.

See [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21530&st=&pgnum=57) for a scanned copy, and [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9F/%D7%99) for a typed version with hyperlinks.

As an aside, I'm not at all sure whether the Torah scrolls commonly produced today follow this tradition.

Comment: No "standard format" Torah scroll written nowadays incorporates these yuds.

Comment: There are _very_ few sifrei torah that follow any of sefer tagin. The last vestige is the large and small letters (which aren’t weird), and the “broken vav” of parshas pinchas (which is also falling out of practice). The best place to look for a comprehensive analysis of “weird letters” in the Torah is volume 29 of תורה שלמה. The essays in the back are about the script of the Torah, and section 2 is in general about sefer tagim. Pg 140-183 has examples of the way that they used to make these special letters. It is very evident that they have fallen out of use.

Comment: After working with Sofrim for many years, it became evident that these haven't fallen out of use, but rather since Sofrus is a craft that mandates being taught from a living teacher to student type of Mesorah... if there are no longer any living teachers that had used these types of letters, then it can no longer be taught.  Many of these Sofrim were murdered during the Holocaust and only a few of these Torah scrolls still exist.